# How to spin a sphere around its own axis in opengl es

Tags: android, iphone, animation, graphics, opengl-es

I am making a solar system project . My sun is stationary at (0,0,0) and my earth is stationary at (0,0,45). now I want my earth to rotate around its own axis while remaining fixed at its position . I "DO NOT" want my earth to rotate in an orbit around the sun . I just want my earth to spin like a globe at fixed position, guys please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the translation 1st and then rotation:

```
glPush()
glTranslate(0,0,45)
glRotate(angle, 0, 1, 0)
glDraw()
glPop()
```

Just as a note, for orbiting it would be:

```
glPush()
glRotate(angle, 0, 1, 0)
glTranslate(0,0,45)
glRotate(-angle, 0, 1, 0)//without this it would rotate around its axis and orbit around sun
glDraw()
glPop()
```

Comment: Then some code might help solve this problem. Can you pleas post the code relative to the matrices and draw calls.